# MS Access link to SQL Server - validate input against 2nd table?

Tags: sql-server, validation, ms-access

I'm trying to think of the easiest way for non-tech users to dump info into a database, without coding my own web application.

Essentially, they are recording subjective phone grading scores for employees.

I linked an Access form to our MS SQL Server database. The only validation I want it -- I want one field, 'employee' - to be validated against a list of employees from say table.employee on SQL Server.

Once the form is submitted it will be written to table.scorecard -- or what have you.

Is this possible in Access? Their standard validation rules don't seem to cover this. Also, is there simply a better way to accomplish this task in general? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem.

The simplest is to use a combobox field for your employee information. Use the employee table as the list data source for the combobox and then set the LimitToList property to true. This assumes that you have setup linked table connections for both your employee table and your 'scores' table.

The second solution is to create a foreign key between the employeeId (or whatever the key field is) in the scores table and the employee table on the SQL side. If someone tries to insert an invalid employee, you will get an insert error. Unfortunately, SQL errors tend to be very confusing to most Access users.

If you want to be very through, you could implement both solutions, this would prevent someone going straight to the linked tables and putting in bad data.

I just realized that I am assuming that you are doing proper relational design where the 'scores' table would contain the employeeId rather than a full name. The idea on the form is to have the combobox display the name, but insert the employeeid field.